# Drush error: "ContainerAwareEventDispatcher" does't implement EventDispatcherInterface::getListenerPriority

Tags: drush, 8, event-subscribers

I'm using Drupal 8.1.2 and Drush 8.1.2 (OS X 10.11.5, PHP 5.6.19)

In all of my drush-commands, there occurs an error, that there is a missing implementations of the symfony `EventDispatcherInterface::getListenerPriority` in the drupal core.

The error occurs on clean drupal installations and also on updated. I've tried to solve the problem by installing a different drupal-version (older and latest ->8.1.2) and older drush-versions (via composer, 8.1.0), but without any results.

This is the my stacktrace:

```
localhost:web3 myusername$ drush up
PHP Fatal error:  Class Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::getListenerPriority) in /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php on line 233
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:0
PHP   2. drush_main() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:12
PHP   3. Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc:66
PHP   4. drush_bootstrap_to_phase() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php:59
PHP   5. drush_bootstrap() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:473
PHP   6. Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrap_drupal_full() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:354
PHP   7. Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_drupal_full() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php:135
PHP   8. drush_cache_get() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot.php:537
PHP   9. dt() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/cache.inc:75
PHP  10. Drupal::translation() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:163
PHP  11. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal.php:592
PHP  12. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
PHP  13. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:329
PHP  14. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
PHP  15. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
PHP  16. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:236
PHP  17. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
PHP  18. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
PHP  19. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:236
PHP  20. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
PHP  21. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
PHP  22. spl_autoload_call() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:272
PHP  23. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader->loadClass() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:0
PHP  24. require() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/vendor/symfony/class-loader/ApcClassLoader.php:110


Call Stack:
    0.0001     225296   1. {main}() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:0
    0.0012     391568   2. drush_main() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:12
    0.2267    8520768   3. Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc:66
    0.2292    8527928   4. drush_bootstrap_to_phase() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php:59
    0.3374    8636336   5. drush_bootstrap() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:473
    0.3376    8638920   6. Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot8->bootstrap_drupal_full() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/bootstrap.inc:354
    0.3921   16940128   7. Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_drupal_full() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot8.php:135
    0.3955   17096672   8. drush_cache_get() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot.php:537
    0.3956   17097472   9. dt() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/cache.inc:75
    0.3957   17098416  10. Drupal::translation() /Users/myusername/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:163
    0.3957   17098464  11. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal.php:592
    0.3958   17106856  12. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
    0.3979   17338080  13. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:329
    0.3979   17338520  14. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
    0.3979   17345920  15. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
    0.3979   17345920  16. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:236
    0.3993   17525976  17. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
    0.3993   17533424  18. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
    0.3993   17533424  19. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:236
    0.4005   17688296  20. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:494
    0.4007   17817768  21. Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:177
    0.4007   17818600  22. spl_autoload_call() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:272
    0.4008   17818880  23. Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader->loadClass() /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php:0
    0.4011   17866704  24. require('/Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php') /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/vendor/symfony/class-loader/ApcClassLoader.php:110

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                                                                 [error]
Error: Class Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface::getListenerPriority) in /Users/myusername/Projects/drupal/web3/core/lib/Drupal/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php, line 233
```

I'm pretty sure that this error is drush-related. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a site-local Drush instead of a globally installed Drush.

See:

https://pantheon.io/blog/avoiding-dependency-hell-site-local-drush

Comment: Thanks Greg! I didn't knew this was possible. It works now with your solution :)

Comment: I must mention here, that basic drush commands are working now, but when I use `$ drush up drupal`, the following error occurs: `Unable to load class \Drush\VersionControl\Backup`

Comment: Run with --debug, and report the results in the Drush issue queue. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues